# atg.repository.RemovedItemException when trying to add an item to Repository

Tags: exception, atg, atg-dynamo, atg-dust

I have used `InternalProfileFormHandler` to add an item `InternalProfileRepository`. It has successfully added the item(user:iuser310002) to the intended repository. Once added, I have accessed dyn/admin to open the repository and removed item I have just added by using `<remove-item item-descriptor="user" id="iuser310002" />`. Then I have used invoked InternalProfileFormHandler again to add one more item. However this time, I have got an `atg.repository.RemovedItemException` saying that `Attempt to use an item which has been removed: user:iuser310002.`

I'm not sure why it is trying to create a new user with same id as before and even if I did, why an item which is removed should cause this issue. I'm using default idGenerator `/atg/dynamo/service/IdGenerator` for InternalProfileRepository so I don't think I would be generating same id.

Here is the code that succesfully created item once and failing from second time...

```
FormHandlerInvoker invoker = new FormHandlerInvoker("/atg/userprofiling/InternalProfileFormHandler", Nucleus.getSystemNucleus());

try {
    String paramName;
    int paramCounter = 1;
    while((paramName = (String) getCurrentTestParams().get("param" + paramCounter)) != null)
    {
        invoker.addInput(paramName, (String) getCurrentTestParams().get("value" + paramCounter));
        paramCounter++;
    }
} catch (ServletException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
FormHandlerInvocationResult result;
ProfileFormHandler formHandler = null;
try {
    result = invoker.invoke();
    formHandler =
    (ProfileFormHandler)result.getDefaultFormHandler();
    formHandler.handleCreate(result.getRequest(), result.getResponse());
}
```

Following is the exception log... which is caused by formHandler.handleCreate method invocation.

```
atg.repository.RemovedItemException: Attempt to use an item which has been removed: user:iuser310002
    at atg.adapter.gsa.ItemTransactionState.<init>(ItemTransactionState.java:385)
    at atg.adapter.gsa.GSAItem.getItemTransactionState(GSAItem.java:2421)
    at atg.adapter.gsa.GSAItem.getItemTransactionState(GSAItem.java:2364)
    at atg.adapter.gsa.GSAItem.getItemTransactionStateUnchecked(GSAItem.java:2600)
    at atg.adapter.gsa.GSAItem.getPropertyValue(GSAItem.java:1511)
    at atg.repository.RepositoryItemImpl.getPropertyValue(RepositoryItemImpl.java:151)
    at atg.adapter.composite.CompositeItem.createPropertyQuery(CompositeItem.java:739)
    at atg.adapter.composite.CompositeItem.getPropertyLinkedItem(CompositeItem.java:630)
    at atg.adapter.composite.CompositeItem.getContributingItem(CompositeItem.java:577)
    at atg.adapter.composite.CompositeItem.findContributingItem(CompositeItem.java:561)
    at atg.adapter.composite.MutableCompositeItem.findContributingItem(MutableCompositeItem.java:971)
    at atg.adapter.composite.MutableCompositeItem.getOrCreateContributingItem(MutableCompositeItem.java:985)
    at atg.adapter.composite.MutableCompositeItem.setPropertyValue(MutableCompositeItem.java:210)
    at atg.userprofiling.ProfileForm.updateProfileAttributes(ProfileForm.java:3761)
    at atg.userprofiling.ProfileForm.updateProfileAttributes(ProfileForm.java:3528)
    at atg.userprofiling.ProfileForm.createUser(ProfileForm.java:1507)
    at atg.userprofiling.ProfileForm.handleCreate(ProfileForm.java:1214)
    at atg.userprofiling.ProfileFormHandler.handleCreate(ProfileFormHandler.java:402)
    at atg.scenario.userprofiling.ScenarioProfileFormHandler.handleCreate(ScenarioProfileFormHandler.java:599)
    at atg.test.steps.CreateInternalUserStep.runTest(CreateInternalUserStep.java:45)
```

Answer (score 0):

After some digging around, I figured out the reason. Along with creating user, a session is also being created for the same user automatically. The user could be found by going to this path in dyn/admin. `/atg/dynamo/servlet/sessiontracking/GenericSessionManager/notdefined/atg/userprofiling/Profile/`

Next time when I'm deleting the item in InternalProfileRepository, the item is being deleted successfully but the session object still exists.

When I call the formhandler.handleCreate again, it is checking if the profile object exists. When it found the user, it is trying to update the same user instead of creating a new one. Hence I'm getting the RemovedItemException.

However, I'm not quite sure if that is what is expected.

Comment: That is basically how it works. So in order for you to delete the profile you need to logout first (or kill your session) and then call RemoveItem.

Comment: aaah... Thanks for confirming. However I have a subsequent doubt, we have also got this issue when we are adding some test data and removing them after our tests. Not profile data, some new catalog etc., are added before tests, and removed after the tests. This is causing the same issue mentioned in the question when we try to run the tests again without restart the server. Do you suggest any work around? would killing session work here as well?

Comment: How many instances are you running and what type of caching have you got set-up? Perhaps that is also causing you a problem. Clear your repository cache after you've removed the items and see if it is still a problem.

Comment: @radimpe  We run single instance. Cache is simple, but we never tried it. Will give it a shot thanks.